# Laravel 4 parameter as controller action

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to know if there is a possibility in Laravel 4 to actually call function of controller based on parameter given. For example if I have route like :

```
'auth/{action}
```

then is there a way to call controller action based on 'action' param ? In Kohana I could write something like:

```
'auth/<action>' -> defaults (controller=>'UserController',action=>'<action>'
```

Well not exacly like that but you know what I mean :) Anyway if there is no chance to do that then do I have to split my route to single routes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to route to the controller with `auth` being the base URI.

```php
Route::controller('auth', 'AuthController');
```

This controller (`AuthController`) now expects your methods to be prefixed with the HTTP verb they should respond to. You can also use the `getIndex` method to respond to the base URI, which in this case is `auth`.

An example controller might look something like this:

```php
class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'Index page'; // Responds to localhost/auth
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return 'Login page'; // Responds to localhost/auth/login
    }

}
```

There is one thing you should be aware of. If you do `Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');` then it should be LAST. Any routes after it will not get called because of Laravel automatically adding a "missing method" route that will catch *anything* that isn't matched by a routable method on the controller.

More on **[RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)** at the official documentation.

Comment: OK that works very well except that I can't use parameters in urls. What is your recommendation ? As far as I know this is crucial in REST API to have possibility to call something like /api/item/1 or stuff. OK I guess I have to use Route::resource in that case. Am I right or should I use Route::controller and somehow pass parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this exact code, but I used something similar and it worked:

```php
Route::any('auth/{action}', function($action){
    $controller = new UserController();
    $controller->$action();
});
```

You might find you also need to handle parameters, like this:

```php
Route::any('auth/{action}/{param}', function($action, $param){
    $controller = new UserController();
    $controller->$action($param);
});
```

You could even tweak it to cover all your controllers:

```php
Route::any('{controller}/{action?}/{param?}', function($controller,$action='index',$param=null)
{
    $controller = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $controller))).'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller;
    $action = lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $action))));
    return $controller->$action($param);
});
```

If you wanted to have an index action with a parameter, that wouldn't work, but otherwise, it seems to work well enough.  It's also not going to handle a second parameter, if you were wanting to do that.

Lots of ways you could extend this idea.

Jason's answer is more correct, (matches the docs, cleaner code, etc.) but if you didn't want to think about HTTP methods, or you wanted a sort of master route to handle nearly every request, this is an option.